# JVM variable not set correctly enough for Android Studio

Tags: windows-xp, java, android-studio, jvm

Having trouble firing up android studio. I get the following message: The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of ?C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre and every other variation I can guess) does not point to a valid JVM installation. I am trying to do this on a windows xp desktop.
I just installed Android Studio and the jdk file today.

Comment: Android Studio requires Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista (32- or 64-bit) (from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements)

Answer (score 2):

Faced the exact same problem but mine was with OS Windows 10. I did twice the same procedure(Creating new environment variable "JAVA_HOME", putting the path to the value field and reboot the system) but unfortunately it didn't work. Then I noticed that both my JDK and JAVA were installed for x64 and the default "studio.exe" was for x86. They have different .exe file for x64 named as "studio64.exe". After executing "studio64.exe", it was always good to go.

Answer (score 0):

#### The environment variable `JAVA_HOME` does not point to a valid JVM installation

`JAVA_HOME` should be set to the root of your Java installation.

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\
```

or add this value to the system environment variables.

See [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for more information.

Note:

- Android Studio is not supported on Windows XP

> Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista (32- or 64-bit)

Source [System Requirements](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements)